# Get item stocks from SAP service layer

Tags: sapb1

I'm working on an integration of SAP with e-commerce and my requirement is to get item stocks and update them on the e-commerce platfrom. Is there any way so that we can fetch only product stocks?

I was fetching the items based on last updated date and time. But, the limitation I'm facing is that the **UpdateDate** and **UpdateTime** fields works only if you make changes directly from the items.But it doesn't work if for example I add a new stock on specific item or place a order and the stock is commited.

Any kind of information is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLQueries](https://blogs.sap.com/2021/01/08/new-sap-business-one-service-layer-sql-query/) from service layer. You need to write query and save it with SQLQueries  and then you can directly call that query from servcie layer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, As you suggested I'm trying to use the SQL queries.
but getting the **502 Proxy Error** while creating the SQL query   

SQL Query:- `SELECT ItemCode, SUM(OnHand) AS InStock, SUM(IsCommited) AS Committed, SUM(OnOrder) AS Ordered FROM oitw WHERE ItemCode IN (:itemList) AND WhsCode NOT IN (:whList) GROUP BY ItemCode`  


itemList and whList are the lists of warehouse and item codes that will be passed as params.

Comment: Unfortunatly there are some limitations about query you can save. 
You can't have parameters in "IN" clause.
Check "4.6 SQL Keywords" in user manual Working with SAP Business One Service Layer

Comment: can you please suggest some alternatives?  thanks!

Comment: For that purpose I would directly  query database without service layer or SDK.

Comment: But my requirement is to integrate SAP with e-commerce(Magento 2) and as far as I know, the only way to establish the connection between them is through the service layer.

Comment: For reading data you can directly query database but you cann't perform any other operation.